# CakeDC users plugin breaking when extending users controller

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to restrict access to administering users in the CakeDC Users plugin. As far as I can tell that requires extending the UsersController, but I can't seem to get that right: something is broken no matter what I do (I've spent a couple days on this).

I've been following the instructions in the Users plugin readme: https://github.com/CakeDC/users. I copied the render method from the readme to use the plugin's views. I overrode `_setupAuth` with an empty function but then copied most of the original `_setupAuth` to my `beforeFilter`:

**AppUsersController.php:**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->allow('login');

        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'),
                'userModel' => 'Users.User',
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.active' => 1,
                    'User.email_verified' => 1)
            )
        );

        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'login');
    }
```

I entered the routes changing them for my extended controller like the readme says with only a couple changes. First I added admin routes, because the admin side was still using the original plugin's controller. Second, I switched `users/users/:action` route with `users/:action` because I kept getting missing method errors (i.e. '/users/users/login' was trying to find users action in a users controller in my app, not in the plugin).

**routes.php:**

```
Router::connect('/admin/users', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/admin/users/index/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/admin/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/admin/users/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/users', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users'));
Router::connect('/users/index/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users'));
Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users'));
Router::connect('/users/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users'));
Router::connect('/login/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/register/*', array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

Now it sort of works. the `admin_edit`, and `view` actions give SQL errors. They seem to depend on some behavior that isn't being loaded for some reason when using my AppUsersController. They call `User->edit` and `User->view` respectively on the User Model. No loaded behaviors implement those methods, so the User Model tries to pass it to the DataSource, hence the SQL errors. Also the `edit` action errors out on `User->UserDetails` not being set to an instance of an object. Is the User Model not being initialized somehow?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by inserting `CakeLog:debug()` into suspect functions in the User Plugin code to see what wasn't being run.

I had to initialize the User model in my AppUsers controller that was extending the plugin's Users controller:

At top:

```
App::uses('User', 'Users.Model');
```

In beforeFilter:

```
$this->User = ClassRegistry::init('Users.User');
```

I knew that I would have to do that for my extended model if I was extending the model, but I am not (yet), so I thought I didn't need to.